# Grant to sys.v_$session

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-grant

I would like to give select grant to sys.v_$session to myUser;
I tried this and got error ORA-01031 "insufficient privileges"

```
grant select on sys.v_$session to myUser;
```

the problem is that I don't have access to the `SYS` user (only SYSTEM)

Can I get grant to sys's table from system user?

Comment: You should give  select_catalog_role to your or schema. 
Using this 
grant select_catalog_role to schemaname;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give select_catalog_role to your schema.

Using this 
grant select_catalog_role to schemaname;

Answer (score 0):

Someone must have access to **SYS**.

Go and ask them to give you permission on v_$session. They must be the ones to give you read access to the system views.

There is no way to avoid it. SYS or not.